# Textarea new line Problems (ASP Classic)

Tags: jquery, asp-classic, get, textarea

I have a textarea value:

```
<textarea id="body">
```

I am passing this value to another page through a get array using jquery:

```
var body = $('#body').val();

window.open("url?body=" + body, ...etc....)
```

I am getting the value on the new page but when I display it there are no line breaks.

So if the user pushes "Enter" to start a new line, it correctly displays on the first page and in the alert of the first page, but when it is used in the second page it is incorrect:

For example:

```
12345
12345
12345
```

Becomes:

```
123451234512345
```

And:

```
Hello World
How are you?
```

Becomes:

```
Hello WorldHow are you?
```

I alert the value on the first page before being passed and it seems that the "alerted" value has the line breaks.

I have tried replacing new line code with a break:

```
body.replace(/\n\r?/g, '<br />');
```

But this did not work.  Any pointers?

The pages are ASP Classic pages.

Thanks

Comment: Can you try it with text() instead of val()?

Comment: Are the line breaks there if you write it out in a `pre` tag?

Comment: So it's ok if you alert it in JS but not when it reaches the destination page. Have you tried viewing the source of the destination page to see if there is any indication there?

Comment: @Martin: I have.  There are no newline characters in the source.

Comment: @Polynomial: I did try, same outcome accept you can now see <pre> and </pre> in the textarea on the second page

Comment: I'm just asking because of your edit... have all the spaces disappeared too?  I think this is something to do with posted values being URL encoded. (Although I thought if you picked up a textarea's val() with jquery it was automatically encoded).

Comment: @MartinHansenLennox: No it does not ignore spaces.  So: 123 456\n123 appears as 123 456123

Comment: I think I'm out of ideas then... sorry... good luck!

Comment: @LajosArpad: I tried .text to the same outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you passing the textarea input to the second page via a form submission.  If you are then give your textarea a name attribute - eg `name="body"`, and then on the target page use

```
<%= (replace(request("body"),chr(13),"<br />")) %>
```

If you've ever used php this essentially does the same as nl2br()

Edit - save this with an .asp file extension and try it

```
<html>
 <body>
 <%= (replace(request("body"),chr(13),"<br />")) %><br /><br />
  <form method="post">
    <textarea name="body" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am passing the textarea value through the get array.  Request.QuesryString("body")

Comment: That should work.  Request.Querystring if you're using the GET method, Request.Form if you're using POST, or just Request will collect variables from either method

Comment: unfortunately the same outcome still.  It's like when it gets to the second page, the new line characters just aren't there to replace.  Seems that somehow all "\n" are being removed when passed through the GET array.

Comment: Try method="post" and Request.Form("body").  Also, you could try vbcrlf or chr(10) in place of chr(13).

Comment: post method worked.  even got to use javascript to build the whole hidden form.  Now I know thanks..  FYI using post, didn't need to use any replace methods,